# Why changing a scope won't work inside a ng-if but via function call - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

Following are the code snippets in which I am toggling the `hideQA` value, the value is changing properly in both condition but not hiding the divs properly if I am doing -

```
`<button ng-click="hideQA = !hideQA">Reset</button>`
```

But it is working correctly if I am changing the value from a method, like -

```
`<button ng-click="resetForm()">Reset</button>`
```

Can anyone explain the reason behind this ?

Working Plnkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/rIAAcibX2Ts1VaMWKQtc?p=preview

Comment: I think it has to do with your comparison.  I created a similar toggle earlier: https://jsfiddle.net/oa4b75zj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-if` has its own `$scope`and when the element is removed, the `$scope` removes too. So you have to reference to parent scope using `$parent`

```
<button ng-click="$parent.hideQA = !hideQA">Reset</button>
```

Another option is to use `ng-show`

```
<div class="message" ng-show="hideQA !== false">
    This is div two !!!
    <button ng-click="hideQA = !hideQA">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Comment: it's better to use dot notation isntead of $parent.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the limit of inhertance between scope.

In order to have no problem with that you must use dot notation.

See the plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/ES9qTl7nsmGGOJnE0H8u?p=preview

See article for more explanation about dot notation

Here is what look like your code with dot notation :

```
<button ng-click="a.hideQA = !a.hideQA">Reset</button>
$scope.a = {hideQA:false};
$scope.a.hideQA = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer given above already solve this issue. Here is my working plunkr link: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZdL441bBmQToGZn4gfQt?p=preview. And I'll say something else:

When you use `ng-if` it will creates its own scope, from angularjs official docs :

> The scope created within ngIf inherits from its parent scope using [prototypal inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#javascript-prototypal-inheritance).

In a short, when refers the value from it's parent scope, only value is copied for primary type (like `string`, `integer` , `boolean` and etc.) but not value's reference (or `pointer`). Which means it is one-way reference not the two-way. So in order to use as two-way the best practice is to always use `javascript object {attr: value}`. And that is why `.` is recommended.

Here is a very good article which worth 20 mins readying about the scopes https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Hope this can help you :)